# Plotting biomass data by time from .nc file in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, latitude-longitude, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a .nc file for planktons' biomass with "lon, lat, time" dimensions are "180, 125 ve 480". Time data is numeric, starting with 1,2,3,....480. It represents the years between 1980-2000. I want to plot biomass by years. So I need to take an average of lon and lat by the same time values? Here's my code. But when I run, it gives an empty plot:

'''

```
library(ncdf4)
library(tidyverse)

our_nc_data <- nc_open("corr_eco3m_bs44_conversion_factor_v7_withDetritus_MEECE.nc")
print(our_nc_data)

lat <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "latitude")
lon <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "longitude")
time <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "time")

nt <- dim(time)

start_date <- as.Date("1980-01-01")
time_seq <- seq(start_date, by = "15 days", length.out = nt)

biomass_array <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "Zo")
fillvalue <- ncatt_get(our_nc_data, "Zo", "_FillValue")

biomass_array[biomass_array == fillvalue$value] <- NA

lonlattime <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lon, lat, time_seq))
head(lonlattime)
dim(lonlattime)

biomass_vec_long <- as.vector(biomass_array)
biomass_vec_long
length(biomass_vec_long)

biomass_obs <- data.frame(cbind(lonlattime, biomass_vec_long))
head(biomass_obs)

colnames(biomass_obs) <- c("Long", "Lat", "Date", "Biomass_Zo")
head(biomass_obs)

biomass_final <- na.omit(biomass_obs)
head(biomass_final)
dim(biomass_final)

biomass_final <- biomass_final[-c(1:2)]

glimpse(biomass_final)

biomass_final$Date <- as.Date(biomass_final$Date)
biomass_final$Biomass_Zo <- as.double(biomass_final$Biomass_Zo)


# Take the mean 
biomass_final <- biomass_final %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(Mean_biomass = mean(Biomass_Zo, na.rm = TRUE))

write.csv(as.data.frame(lswt_final), "Zo_biomass.csv", row.names=T)


# Plot the data using ggplot2
ggplot(biomass_final, aes(x = Date, y = Mean_biomass)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Biomass_Zo") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

'''

Comment: can you `dput(head(our_nc_data))` so we can get a better view of what you're working with please?

Comment: list(filename = "corr_eco3m_bs44_conversion_factor_v7_withDetritus_MEECE.nc", 
    writable = FALSE, id = 262144L, error = FALSE, safemode = FALSE, 
    format = "NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC")

Comment: and for `biomass_final` as well please?

Comment: Sure! > dput(head(biomass_final))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(3652, 3667, 3682, 3697, 3712, 
3727), class = "Date"), Mean_biomass = c(7.40254209928812e+35, 
159.139770071623, 262.03385048119, 275.716041716774, 48.992811774022, 
7.42591774539943)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this with the `dput` you kindly provided and I get a non-empty plot.
I replaced `size =`  with `linewith =` as `size` is deprecated, and I converted to a log scale as you have such a large range in your `Mean_biomass` values:

```
ggplot(biomass_final, aes(x = Date, y = Mean_biomass)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Biomass_Zo") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]